# Oracle query where field1=field2 and field2=field1

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table that holds a link relationship.  Field1 is and ID and Filed2 is an ID.  So far I've eliminated duplicate Field1\Field2 combinations.  However I still have cases where the inverse occurs.  Meaning Field1 occurs as Field2 and Field2 occurs in Field1 for the same record.  I tried a subquery within in inner join but it's returning way to many rows.  Thanks in advance!

```
select a.field1, a.field2 from linktable
inner join (select field1, field2 from linktable) b on a.field1=b.field2 and a.field2=b.field1;
```

Sample data:

```
insert into linktable(field1, field2) values ('ABC', '123');
insert into linktable(field1, field2) values ('123', 'ABC');
```

I want to identify and remove cases where the above sample data occurs.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you the pairs:

```
SELECT a.field1, a.field2
  FROM linktable a
  JOIN linktable b ON (b.field1 = a.field2 AND b.field2 = a.field1)
```

Edit: An example of finding one of the pairs:

```
create table linktable(id number, field1 varchar2(32), field2 varchar2(32));
insert into linktable(id, field1, field2) values (1, 'ABC', '123');
insert into linktable(id, field1, field2) values (2, '123', 'ABC');

SELECT a.field1, a.field2, LEAST(a.id, b.id) AS id_to_delete
  FROM linktable a
  JOIN linktable b ON (b.field1 = a.field2 AND b.field2 = a.field1);
```

Result:

```
FIELD1  FIELD2  ID_TO_DELETE
123     ABC     1
ABC     123     1
```

Comment: I think this is it.  It actually returns the same # of results as my query I just couldn't believe it could be right.  Now the trick is, how to remove one and keep the other.

Comment: Is there a rule you can come up with to decide which of the pair you prefer?  Something like "the one with the maximum id"?  Because then you can add something like `LEAST(a.id, b.id)` to the query and use those as the identifiers to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select field1, field2
from (select field1, field2, 
             row_number() over (partition by least(field1, field2), greatest(field1, field2) order by field1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one instance of `field1`/`field2` regardless of ordering.

Comment: I want to try this more but it says I'm missing an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

You should post sample data and expected result.

I think this query may work for you, this prevent the inverse occurs as `field1, field2` = `(x, y)` and `(y, x)`

```
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM linktable
WHERE field1 >= field2;
```